# Access the native Apple Messages app from my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to create an app that accesses the native Apple Messages app - i want to be able to 
1. integrate the Apple Messages app inside my app and
2 i want to be able to know when the user sends and when they receive a message - is this possible ? any help or direction on this is greatly appreciate it thx

Comment: It won't be accepted by the App store, each App is sandboxed to its own resources and therefore can't do what you want. Someone might be able to help you do it if your willing to distribute it through Cydia

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. File a bug to request this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)?  It lets your users compose and send SMS messages within your application.

The delegate for this controller will receive a callback that indicates whether or not the message was actually set.